# gdalinfo documentation includes -json flag but using it returns "FAILURE: Unknown option name '-json'"

Tags: gdal

Reading the [documentation for gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) describes the option of formatting the output as JSON.

> -json
>
> > Display the output in json format.

However, when I use the `-json` tag it appears not to be implemented.

> > gdalinfo -json translated_image_overlay.png
>     Usage: gdalinfo [--help-general] [-mm] [-stats] [-hist] [-nogcp] [-nomd]
>                               [-norat] [-noct] [-nofl] [-checksum] [-proj4]
>                               [-listmdd] [-mdd domain|`all`]*
>                               [-sd subdataset] datasetname
>
> FAILURE: Unknown option name '-json'

I have GDAL 1.11.1 installed.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-json was implemented in GDAL 2.0+.  1.11.1 does not have this feature.

see here:
http://gdal.org/1.11/gdalinfo.html

Comment: Thanks @Thomas-horner, great answer. Do you(,or someone else,) happen to know where I can download GDAL 2.0+ core and Python bindings for Windows x86_64?

Comment: Easiest way is to just download the OSGeo4W network installer.  You can install a variety of FOSS4G, including the latest gdal versions. https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Another source for Windows builds is http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php. Just select your processor and a MSVC version. The benefit of gisinternals is that it does not interfere with running QGIS/GDAL versions if you use the zipped versions. Start the SDK shell, and run commands at the console inside.